# How is $\mathbb R$ with the usual addition and the Euclidean topology a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

If $m: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, I am having trouble seeing how $m^{-1}((0,1))$ is open in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$?

I know that $\{(x,y) \mid 0<x,y<1/2\}\subset m^{-1}((0,1))$ and $\{(x,y) \mid 1/2<x<1, 0<y<1/2\}\subset m^{-1}((0,1))$.

In general, $m^{-1}((0,1))=\{(x,y)\mid 0<x+y<1\}=\{(x,y)\mid -y<x<1-y\}$.

But what is the whole set $m^{-1}((0,1))$?

Comment: How about $\{(x,y): x>0, 0<y<1/x\} \cup \{(x,y): x<0, 1/x<y<0\}$?

Comment: Should the $1/x$ be $1-x$ since we are considering $\mathbb R$ with addition?

Comment: $m$ ordinarily stands for multiplication!! This is why you need to state everything in the body of the question. So you answered your own question. What do you mean "what is the whole set"?

Comment: The whole set **is** $\{(x,y) : 0< x+ y < 1\}$ by definition. But even if you show it to be open, it shows nothing yet, as you want to do this for *all* open sets not just $(0,1)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see how $m^{-1}((a,b))=\{(x,y)\mid a-y<x<b-y\}$ is enough to show that $m$ is continuous, but what does $m^{-1}((0,1))$ look like in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $m^{-1}((a,b))=\{(x,y)\mid a-y<x<b-y\}$ is enough to show that $m$ is continuous.

Comment: You can't draw $\{(x,y): a<x+y<b\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$?  Hint: Sketch $x+y=a$ and $x+y=b$ with dotted lines. It's clearer to write it this way, by the way.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh ok. Wow. I guess I was confused because I was writing $m^{-1}((a,b))=\{(x,y)\mid a-y<x<b-y\}$. I can see it much clearer if I write it how you did above: $m^{-1}((a,b))=\{(x,y)\mid a-x<y<b-x\}$. Now I can see $y$ as a function of $x$. [ Also, it's late here :) ]

Comment: You have to use the product topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, not write $x$ in terms of $y$ etc. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $m: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is addition, so $m(x,y) = x+y$, then let $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open, and consider $m^{-1}[O]$. To see it is open we show that $(p,q) \in m^{-1}[O]$ is an interior point of it, so let $(p,q) \in m^{-1}[O]$, which means that $m(p,q) = p+q \in O$. As $O$ is open, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open interval $(p+q-\varepsilon, p+q+\varepsilon) \subseteq O$, by the (or a) definition of the topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Now, $$(p,q) \in U:=(p-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, p+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \times (q-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, q+\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$$ and $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the product topology. It's clear from the ordered field properties of $\mathbb{R}$ that $U \subseteq m^{-1}[O]$, showing $(p,q)$ to be an interior point of $O$:

$(x,y) \in U$ iff $p - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < x < p+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and
$q-\frac{\varepsilon}{2} < y < q+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ so that (adding these inequalities), we have $p+q -\varepsilon< x+y < p+q+\varepsilon$, so $m(x,y) \in O$ as required.

As we already know we have a group, for proving the group operation continuous it suffices it to be continuous at $(0,0)$ and so we could have limited ourselves to checking sets $m^{-1}[(-r,r)]$ to be open for all $r>0$, as such sets form a local base at $0$. This is entirely similar: just note that $(-\frac{r}{2}, \frac{r}{2}) \times (-\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2})$ will do as a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ that maps to $(-r,r)$ under $m$, but slightly easier maybe.

Comment: Instead of considering $O$, we can just consider a basis element of $\mathbb R$, say $(a,b)$.

Comment: We could even go easier and just consider $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @AlJebr limiting to rational endpoints makes no difference. You just need properties of addition like $x<a$ and $y < b$ implies $x+y < a+b$ etc, which hold for all reals.